# How to enable displaying "Choose column to display" in phpMyAdmin?

Tags: phpmyadmin

I read [here](https://serverfault.com/a/184174) you found a solution to the question in the title:

> How to enable displaying "Choose column to display" in phpMyAdmin?

Could you explain how you enabled that?
I'm using phpMyAdmin under MAMP.

Answer (score 4):

Took me a while to figure this out. Trick was to enable "table_info" in the config.inc.php, like so:

```
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['table_info'] = 'pma_table_info';
```